# Concatenate Multiple media files into one output/listening to Media Foundation Events

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I've written an application that will transcode and manipulate media files using Microsoft Media Foundation, but now I've got to make the same application concatenate/join media files together.

Is there any existing documentation on doing something like this?  Any pointers/hints?  Any existing code that does this?

If not, I figure I've got to write or find a custom media source-something like a ConcatenatingMediaSource(a source that wraps the series of sources it's concatenating together), but I'm unsure if this is the best course to accomplish this.

**EDIT**:
It seems the relevant event I need to be concerned with are MEEndOfPresentation-this indicates that a source(or perhaps one of my embedded sources) has reached the end of all it's streams.

MSDN docs state that if a wrapped source fires this event, I have the ability set a new PresentationDescriptor on my Source.  Perhaps I could just return the next embedded source's PresentationDescriptor?

Right now I'm held up on how to actually *listen* to an individual source's events.  How to do this isn't exactly clear (at least to someone who mostly writes code for the JVM).

**EDIT**:
I think I want to use a [SequenceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms698996%28v=VS.85%29.aspx); it's part of the API but seems fairly undocumented.